# Cannot send image file with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to send an image to server using retrofit, but I get a problem that the image can't be processed by server. Meanwhile, when I test send an image using postman, it works. is I need to convert the file to specific format ?

this is the sample request from postman[image]

ps: I get the FormUtils class from here
https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java

below is my code

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_data_step, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    //imageEktp.setClickable(true);

    getPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Log.d("test : ", "testing");
            CharSequence menu[] = new CharSequence[]{"Take From Galery", "Open Camera"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Pick a Picture");
            builder.setItems(menu, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if(i == 0){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);
                    }else if(i == 1){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Context applicationContext = getActivity();

    if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            final Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            imageEktp.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            /*Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), bitmap);
            File file = new File(get);
            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType()))

            try {
                InputStream streamCamera = applicationContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(bitmap);
                uploadImage(getBytes(streamCamera));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            imageEktp.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            uploadFile(selectedImage);
            Log.d("selected image : ", selectedImage.toString());

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
}

private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri){
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    File file = FileUtils.getFile(getContext(), fileUri);
    //Log.d("file", file.toString());

    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);
    Log.d("imageFile : ", requestFile.toString());
    Call<UploadImageResponse> call = apiService.uploadImage(body);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadImageResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UploadImageResponse> call, Response<UploadImageResponse> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                String getUrlResponse = response.body().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data : " + getUrlResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Log.d("Message Response : ", response.body().getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UploadImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Failure : ", String.valueOf(t));
        }
    });
}
```

this is my apiInterface

```
@Multipart
@POST("v1/upload_doc")
Call<UploadImageResponse> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

Comment: `if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)`. Why did you post that unused code?

Comment: May be the server doesn't support multipart and is expecting a Base64 String representation of the image?